# Capturing matching and non-matching values between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, compare, set-difference

I've done quite a bit of reading on this but I've not been able to get an answer that works yet.

I've been using the `setdiff` function in R to look at the number of matches between two dataframes. I know that I have 71 out of 200 observations matching and the remainder non-matching.

So far I've just done this to get the number of matching and non-matching values:

```
check = setdiff(dataset1$variable1, dataset2$variable1)
```

How do I return a list of the matching and non-matching values?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the matching values are found with the `intersect` function, from the Set Operations. All the values in both variables are found with the `union` function. So the values that are in the union, but not in the intersect are non-matching.

```
var1 <- LETTERS[1:5]
var2 <- LETTERS[4:8]
matched <- intersect(var1, var2)
all <-  union(var1, var2)
non.matched <- all[!all %in% matched]
```

Comment: Thanks Ediwn, I've managed to do it now using these two functions. One other question, in your code, what do 'LETTERS [1:5]' and 'LETTERS[4:8]' mean?

Comment: The letters of the alphabet are built in in R. Entering LETTERS returns all the 26 capital letters. Within the square brackets you create a subset. So var1 is A up untill E, and var2 is D up untill H.

Comment: I am trying to replicate this code, and the resulting 'non.matched' data frame is the same as 'all' data frame. Maybe this needs to be updated.