# How to extract the IDs of non-matching values between 2 data frames by ID in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, compare

I am trying to build a report with all non-matching values between 2 data frames. I was trying to apply the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824878/capturing-matching-and-non-matching-values-between-two-dataframes-in-r), but the `intersect` function does not work due to number of columns being different.

I am using the `comparedf` function from `arsenal` package, which does a good job at showing me the differences between dataframes, but I am not sure how to keep the non-matching rows into another data frame or another vector.

here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var =c(1,3,4,2,5),
                  var2 = c(1,2,4,3,5))

library(arsenal)
summary(comparedf(df1, df2, by ="id"))
```

Which gives the solution here:

```
Table: Differences detected

var.x   var.y   id   values.x   values.y    row.x   row.y
------  ------  ---  ---------  ---------  ------  ------
var     var     b    2          3               2       2
var     var     c    3          4               3       3
var     var     d    4          2               4       4
var2    var2    c    3          4               3       3
var2    var2    d    4          3               4       4
```

Is there a way to extract the IDs from this table as a vector? Or subset the df1 using only these IDs would also work.

Edit: I added another variable column because in my real dataset multiple columns are being compared at the same time.

Comment: Where is `comparedf` from? A quick search suggests there's one version in the package `arsenal`, and there's another in a package called `compareDF`, and possibly others.

Comment: It's from Arsenal. I am sorry, going to update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return a list of the ids from the `comparedf` function

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var =c(1,3,4,2,5))
library(arsenal)
vec1 <- summary(comparedf(df1, df2, by="id"))
df4 <- vec1$diffs.table
list1 <- df4$id
```

Comment: That works! With the vector I can subset the dataframes with only the non-matching IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty approach without any sophisticated packages:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var =c(1,3,4,2,5))

df1$var[df1$id == df2$id] == df2$var
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

df1 |>
  subset(!df1$var[df1$id == df2$id] == df2$var)
#>   id var
#> 2  b   2
#> 3  c   3
#> 4  d   4
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This solution works for this simple example, but in my real data I have about 70 columns being compared at the same time. Maybe I should make it clear in my question, going to update it.